# Is there any difference between using PDO::bindValue (with or without a type identifier) vs execute?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have been using PDO for at least two years now, and I've noticed that all three of these methods are available to bind a value to a query.

Is there any difference, downfall, or reason against doing any of these three. Are they all correct and can be used freely without a consequence?

**Using BindValue with a type identifier**

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `cake` (`name`) VALUES(:name)");
$query->bindValue(":name", $cakeName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
```

**Using BindValue without a type identifier**

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `cake` (`name`) VALUES(:name)");
$query->bindValue(":name", $cakeName);
$query->execute();
```

**Binding the value using an array in an execute value**

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `cake` (`name`) VALUES(:name)");
$query->execute([":name"=>$cakeName]); // shorthand array from PHP 5.4
```

I know this question has been asked before, though I haven't seen which one should be used and how it'll be handled. I also haven't seen one explaining the consequences of not using a type identifier, which is why I feel it's okay to post this. Is not setting it going to use more resources so it can try to judge by itself, is it bad practice not to set it? Just curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference is that `bindValue` allows you to pass a third parameter: the type. With `execute` all values are bound as strings. With `bindValue`, you can bind values as integers, bools, blobs or other types. Sometimes this is absolutely necessary, e.g. for blobs. In other cases it doesn't make much of a difference, e.g. MySQL will handle `WHERE foo = '42'` (bound as string) the same as `WHERE foo = 42` (bound as int).